# How to test a Rails Class function in the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, console, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to test some functions in a Rails Class in the rails console.

```
class Model
  def function1
    input_1 = ...
    input_2 = ...
    function1_hash = [ ]
    ...
    m = function2(input_1,input_2)
    function1_hash += m
  end

  def function2(input_1,input_2)
    input_1.each do |value|
      function2_hash << value
    end

    temp = input_2.anotherClassFunctionCall()
    function2_hash << temp
  end
end
```

So in Rails console, I'm trying to see if these functions are working properly or not but I keep running into the following error.

```
# Rails console
> input_1 = ...
> input_2 = ...
> Model.function2(input_1,input_2)
NoMethodError: undefined method `function2' for Model:Class
```

Ultimately, I need to sanity check function1 (which is definitely failing in the greater workflow), but can't seem to even recognize the functions that it depends on within the same class.

BTW, the entire rails is uploaded as a Docker file in the AWS ELB instance.And I'm using ***eb ssh*** to access rails and perform above tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `function2` is an instance method. You need to call it on instance of `Model` class like:

```
Model.new.function2(input_1,input_2)
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for your input. There is a separate _**def init**_ function prior to function1 and when I use your:

    Model.new.function2(input_1,input_2)

I get the same exception error that is embedded in _**def function1**_ when I run a general _**Model.create!(input_variable: some_varialbe)**_ (--> this is what I need to have working):

    rescue Exception => e
      run_errors << "Error with ..."
      self.state = :error
      throw "Error running this list ..."

How can I check to see what throws the error statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your method a class method

Change:

```
def function2(input_1,input_2)
```

to:

```
def self.function2(input_1,input_2)
```